# Understanding Month Change with DateTimeFormatter#parseLocalDateTime

Tags: jodatime

Given the following `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
scala> val dateTimeFormatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
dateTimeFormatter: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter@163fc8b4
```

Why does passing `"2015-02-05 22:27:36.491"` to the following function decrease the month by 1?

```
scala> dateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDateTime("2015-02-05 22:27:36.491").toDateTime
res5: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2015-01-05T22:27:36.491-05:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the format pattern `m` refers to the minute field. The month field is `M`. You've used the lower-case `m` for both minutes and months.

You should use `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"`, not `"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"`